# Unity button highlight not working properly after spawn

Tags: unity, unity-ui

I am instantiating a UI button. After it spawns if I hover on the button it highlights properly.

The problem is if I spawn the button and the mouse position is already on top of the instantiated button, then the hover event does not trigger.
If I move the mouse away from the button and then back in, then the highlight works.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of solved it, but in a really hacky way.

Since I couldn't refresh the button hover events, I just moved the mouse away from the button for a millisecond and then put it back on top of the button. Which does work, but its not very elegant solution.
Here is the code if anyone has the same problem in the future.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

...

```
int x_Pos, y_Pos;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool GetCursorPos(out int X, out int Y);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

public IEnumerator Mouse_Shuffle() {
    GetCursorPos(out x_Pos, out y_Pos);

    Cursor.visible = false;
    SetCursorPos(0, 0);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.00000000000001f);

    SetCursorPos(x_Pos, y_Pos);
    Cursor.visible = true;
}
```